# How do I get the return type of a member function without an object?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

I have a number of classes that I cannot modify.  Each has a copy constructor, at least one other constructor, and a function `foo()` that returns some value.  I want to make a class template that can derive from each of these classes, and has a data member that is the same type as the return type of `foo()` (sorry if I've got some of the terminology wrong).

In other words, I would like a class template

```
template<typename T> class C : public T
{
  footype fooresult;
};
```

where `footype` is the return type of `T::foo()`.

If the base classes all had, say, a default constructor, I could do

```
decltype(T().foo()) fooresult;
```

(with the C++11 functionality in GCC) but the classes don't have any particular constructor in common, apart from the copy constructors.

GCC also doesn't allow `decltype(this->foo())`, though apparently there is a possibility that this will be added to the C++0x standard - does anyone know how likely that is?

I feel like it should be possible to do something along the lines of `decltype(foo())` or `decltype(T::foo())` but those don't seem to work: GCC gives an error of the form `cannot call member function 'int A::foo()' without object`.

Of course, I could have an extra template parameter `footype`, or even a non-class parameter of type `T`, but is there any way of avoiding this?

Comment: Someone will probably come up with something more elegant, but what about `typename decltype(mem_fun(&T::foo()))::result_type` or some such?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You don't need that- remember that since decltype doesn't evaluate its argument, you can just call on `nullptr`.

```
decltype(((T*)nullptr)->foo()) footype;
```

Answer (score 59):

Another alternative is:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T> class C : public T
{
   decltype(std::declval<T>().foo()) footype;
};
```

`declval` returns a `T&&`.  Or if foo might be overloaded with rvalue-ref qualifiers, and you want to insure you get the lvalue overload of foo:

```
   decltype(std::declval<T&>().foo()) footype;
```

In this example `declval` returns a `T&`.

Like the `((T*)nullptr)->` solution, `std::declval` places no requirements on the type `T`.

Comment: Like this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/2VxofTWyYmYlZDRW

Answer (score 8):

It's also possible to do this using C++17's [`std::invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of), or the deprecated `std::result_of` it replaces:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> class C : public T
{
    using footype = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&T::foo), T>;
    footype fooresult;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another possibility: one only knows the type of a class member function, has no idea either the class instance or how to call the member function, one just wants to extract from, for example `int (IObject::*)(int, float)`, the return type `int`, here is a simple example to demonstrate this situation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class IObject {
public:
    virtual int foo(int, float) = 0;
    virtual double bar(double) = 0;
};


template<typename T>
struct method_return_type;

template<typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct method_return_type<R(C::*)(Args...)> {
    using type = R;
};

template<typename MethodT>
using method_return_type_t = typename method_return_type<MethodT>::type;

template<typename ObjectMethodT>
void some_func() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<method_return_type_t<ObjectMethodT>, int>) {
        std::cout << "do something for int return type" << std::endl;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<method_return_type_t<ObjectMethodT>, double>) {
        std::cout << "do something for double return type" << std::endl;
    } else
        static_assert(!sizeof(ObjectMethodT) && "unexpected type.");
}

int main() {
    some_func<decltype(&IObject::foo)>();
    some_func<decltype(&IObject::bar)>();
}
```

`method_return_type` just extracts the return type from the member function signature.

If by `std::invoke_result_of`, one has to specify the parameter types for member function: `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&IObject::foo), IObject, int, float>`, but function `some_func` may have no idea what these parameter types are.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with which seems to work for most cases.

```
template <typename TYPE, typename FUNCPTR, typename...ARGS>
using mfunc_return_t = decltype((std::declval<TYPE>().*std::declval<FUNCPTR>())(std::declval<ARGS&>()...));
```

Then I use it in a function which calls a provided member function.

```
template <typename FUNCPTR, typename TYPE, typename...ARGS>
mfunc_return_t<TYPE, FUNCPTR, ARGS...> SafeCall(TYPE* ptr, FUNCPTR func, ARGS&...args)
{
    if (ptr != nullptr)
        return (ptr->*func)(args...);
    using ReturnType = mfunc_return_t<TYPE, FUNCPTR, ARGS...>;
    return DefaultValue<ReturnType>();
}
```

I have several implementation of DefaultValue for handling types including arithmetic types, pointers, void, and other default constructable types.

Then I can do things like

```
auto returnVal = SafeCall(pointer, &MyClass::FunctionName, arg1, arg2);
```

or

```
return SafeCall(pointer, &MyClass::FunctionName, arg1, arg2);
```