# convenience function/macro for std::transform

Tags: c++, templates, macros

For fun I try to get the usage of `std::transform` as close as possible to [`map` in Haskell](http://ideone.com/enE1Gc).

My current attempt looks as follows, but I guess it can be done nicer.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename ContainerOut, typename ContainerIn, typename Functor>
ContainerOut mappHelp(const ContainerIn& xs, Functor op)
{
    ContainerOut res;
    res.reserve(xs.size());
    transform(begin(xs), end(xs), back_inserter(res), op);
    return res;
}

#define mapp(f, xs, res) mappHelp<decltype(res)>(xs, [](decltype(xs)::value_type it)f);

int main()
{
    vector<int> xs = {1,2,3};

    // How can we come closer to the following?
    // auto ys = mapp({return it * 1.5;}, xs);
    vector<double> ys = mapp({return it * 1.5;}, xs, ys);

    copy(begin(ys), end(ys), ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ","));
}
```

Any ideas on how to get rid of having to tell the return type to the call (or how to improve it in general)?

Comment: This is way too broad. There are thousands of ways to improve it.

Comment: One possible improvement would be to allow *any* callable object as the function object, and not to force the use of lambdas. First of all it will make the code backward-compatible with C++03, secondly what if the user of your function wants to lower-case a string? Then just passing `std::tolower` as argument is more convenient than writing `{ return std::tolower(it); }`. This change also doesn't force the user of your function to use a pre-defined argument name in lambdas.

Comment: You should if possible ALLWAYS put parentheses around all parameters you use in a macro.  What do you mean with "get rid of the return type" ?

Comment: Since I seem to receive close votes: Would it be better to post this question on codereview.stackexchange?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sounds good. Any hint on how to implement this?

Comment: @Christophe I mean right now I can not use `auto` for the declaration of ys.

Comment: That's normal ! mapp uses ys to determine the return type  (`mappHelp<decltype(res)>`) so with auto, your compiler wouldn't know what to choose !

Comment: @Christophe Yes, I know why this is the case. I wrote it that way. ;) My goal is to get rid of it and let the compile infer it.

Comment: You could infer the type to be used from the return type of the Functor (see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580253/c-template-get-return-type-of-member-function-without-an-object).  But the problem is to infer the container.  I guess it could be done by having a specialisation for each kind of container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do something like:

```
// helper class to rebind a container to use an other type
template<typename Container, typename T> struct rebind;

// specialization for vector
template <typename Tc, typename A, typename T>
struct rebind<std::vector<Tc, A>, T>
{
    using type = std::vector<T, typename A::template rebind<T>::other>;
};
```

And your method

```
template<
    typename F,
    typename C,
    typename ContainerOut =
        typename rebind<C, decltype(std::declval<F>()(*std::begin(std::declval<C>())))>::type
    >
ContainerOut
 mapp(F f, const C& c)
{
    ContainerOut res;
    res.reserve(c.size());
    std::transform(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::back_inserter(res), f);
    return res;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/XDyorY)